# pytest-asyncio, all test passed but got RuntimeError: Event loop is closed Error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, pytest-asyncio

I used pytest-asyncio to test my sqlalchemy[asyncmy] database, All tests passed, but an error was reported.
I don't know how this happened. Is it the plugin itself or something I did wrong?

```bash
================================ 2 passed in 0.32s ======================================
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000183137D28C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Here is my configuration for this test:

**pytest.ini**

```ini
[pytest]
testpaths = test
asyncio_mode=strict
```

**conftest.py**

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    policy = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy()
    loop = policy.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

**test_user_repository.py**

```py
import pytest
from src.repository import user_repositroy
from src.database.dbconfig import mysql_config
from urllib.parse import quote_plus as urlquote
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session():
    default_mysql_config = mysql_config.get('default')
    db_url: str = f"mysql+asyncmy://{default_mysql_config.username}:" \
                  f"{urlquote(default_mysql_config.password)}@" \
                  f"{default_mysql_config.host}:{default_mysql_config.port}/" \
                  f"{default_mysql_config.database}"
    async_engine = create_async_engine(db_url, echo=True, future=True)
    async_session = sessionmaker(bind=async_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False, autoflush=False,
                                 autocommit=False)
    return async_session


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_user_by_id(session):
    async with session() as db:
        user = await user_repositroy.get_user_by_id(db, user_id=1)
    assert user.id == 1


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_user_by_id2(session):
    async with session() as db:
        user = await user_repositroy.get_user_by_id(db, user_id=3)
    assert user.id == 3
```

**user_repository.py**

```py
async def get_user_by_id(db: AsyncSession, user_id: int) -> UserModel:
    stat = select(UserModel).where(UserModel.id == user_id)
    result = await db.scalars(statement=stat)
    return result.one_or_none()
```

Then I ran in the command line:

```bash
> pytest

plugins: anyio-3.6.1, asyncio-0.18.3
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test\test_repository\test_user_repository.py 2022-07-07 17:45:47,668 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2022-07-07 17:45:47,668 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-07-07 17:45:47,670 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
2022-07-07 17:45:47,670 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-07-07 17:45:47,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
2022-07-07 17:45:47,671 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
2022-07-07 17:45:47,673 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-07-07 17:45:47,675 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT user.username, user.password, user.id, user.create_time, user.update_time
FROM user
WHERE user.id = %s
2022-07-07 17:45:47,675 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00027s] (1,)
2022-07-07 17:45:47,676 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
.2022-07-07 17:45:47,679 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2022-07-07 17:45:47,679 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT user.username, user.password, user.id, user.create_time, user.update_time
FROM user
WHERE user.id = %s
2022-07-07 17:45:47,679 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.004879s ago] (3,)
2022-07-07 17:45:47,680 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
.

========================================================================================================== 2 passed in 0.30s ========================================================================================================== 
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000002DBFE0928C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 750, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "D:\Programs\development\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem just now. I think you are missing an "async with" statement:

```
async def get_user_by_id(db: AsyncSession, user_id: int) -> UserModel:
    async with db:
        stat = select(UserModel).where(UserModel.id == user_id)
        result = await db.scalars(statement=stat)
        return result.one_or_none()
```

I am new to this too, but my guess is that you AsyncSession need to be closed. Please can someone chime in and give a better explanation. Thanks.

Comment: He might be using a scoped session so there is no need to open and close the connection as the framework already does that for him on the app context level.

Answer (score 0):

I received an official reply to this question from posting an issue on GitHub. I quote verbatim:

> This happens because the asyncio event loop when using pytest-asyncio
> is created anew for each test execution and the client caches the
> first event loop it finds within each AIOHttpNode instance. To
> work-around this you'll need to create a new instance of
> AsyncElasticsearch for each test execution rather than using a single
> global instance. Hope this helps!

Suffice to say, this can be a painful adjustment if production code relies on one global AsyncElasticSearch instance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AckThpfft could you please send a link to original answer?